# Proving a bound for analytic functions on the disc

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Let $f$ be holomorphic on $|z| < 2$

I want to show that 
$\max_{|z| = 1} | f(x) - {1 \over z}| \geq 1 $

I think the idea is to apply a Mobius transform to $f(x) - {1 \over z}$ and then apply either maximum modulus or the Schwarz principle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integrating the function $f(z)-\dfrac1z$ over the path $|z|=1$ we get
$$
\int_{|z|=1}\left(f(z)-\frac1z\right)dz=-2\pi i.
$$
On the other hand,
$$
\left|\int_{|z|=1}\left(f(z)-\frac1z\right)dz\right|\le\int_{|z|=1}\left|f(z)-\frac1z\right|dz\le2\pi\max_{|z|=1}\left|f(z)-\frac1z\right|.
$$
Hence, $\max_{|z|=1}\left|f(z)-\dfrac1z\right|\ge1$.